# Merge properties of Java.util.Properties into ProperPlaceHolderConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Currently working on Spring Project. 
In my project people are using 2 approaches to load properties file:

1. Using `java.util.Properties`
2. Using `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`

Actually i have jar file which has a java util.Property object and in my main project i want to use it to resolve placeholders in spring xml files.
Is there any way to use Property object to resolve Placeholders or merge them with PropertyPlaceHolderConfiguere object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418786/use-java-util-properties-instead-of-propertyplaceholder-configurator-in-springbe

Comment: I have gone through the question you suggested. It's not related to my question. actually i have jar file which has a java util.Property object and in my main project i want to use it to resolve placeholders in spring xml files

Comment: Is your java.util.Properties object getting scanned in your main spring project ? If not then configure the base package scan to include the package which contains the java.util.Properties. (I assume both the object and your main project are sharing the same spring container / context)

Comment: No, It's not getting scanned in the same project. Even i have Properties class in main project which takes Property Object from jar and Merge it to use in Main project. The only problem is placeholders in xml files. As xml files uses PropertyPlaceHolderConfiguere to resolve placeholders. So wanted to create PropertyPlaceHolderConfiguere object in property class of main project and feed it to xml. Is is going to   work?